# it is possible to app work in background after restarting my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, background-process

I am working location service based iPhone app. I am getting latitude and longitude values foreground an background also. But when i power off and on means my application was not working. how to work automatically my application in background when power off and on my iPhone.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how to get your app working when the phone is turned off ?

Comment: App need to work background when iPhone was turned on.

Comment: So they turn the phone off and then on again ?

Comment: Yes. Turn the phone off and then on.

Comment: Well that's the equivalent of the user completely closing your app from the multi tasking bar. So i'm not sure you can.

Comment: You definitely can't.

Answer (score 0):

The document of apple said :

> Note: If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the
>   system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location
>   updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the
>   delivery of location updates resumes. The only way to have your app
>   relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or the
>   significant-change location service. However, when a user disables the
>   Background App Refresh setting either globally or specifically for
>   your app, the system doesn’t relaunch your app for any location
>   events, including significant-change or region monitoring events.
>   Further, while Background App Refresh is off your app won’t receive
>   significant-change or region monitoring events even when it's in the
>   foreground. When a user reenables Background App Refresh for your app,
>   Core Location restores all background services, including any
>   previously registered regions.

Reference from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

As the document says, you can't get the local information all the time if your iPhone is on. Users can also disable `Background App Refresh setting` or kill your app. So whether it would be relaunched doesn't make much sense.

You can have a try (write some message in a log file in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method). BTW I don't think system will relaunch it.